# What's the difference between tf_kernel_library and cc_library

Tags: build, bazel

I am learning bazel build to compile the tensorflow source code.
In this bazel [build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L409-L436) file, I see '''tf_kernel_library''' and '''cc_library'''.
What is the exact difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

"tf_kernel_library" is a **custome rule** and "cc_library" is a **bazel buildin rule**

- "tf_kernel_library" is a rule to build a TensorFlow OpKernel. The biggest difference from "cc_library" is that "tf_kernel_library" compiles `cu.cc` and `cu.h` in addition to `.cc` and `.h`, while "cc_library" does not.
- "cc_library" builds `.cc` and `.h` only for c++

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. One more question, what does the attribute ```prefix``` mean in the build file. for example, ```prefix = "clustering_ops"```

Comment: prefix seems another way of add srcs and hdrs, You can find more details in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0d0bb68f10a3cff1990167e7f78c854145af2d53/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl